# Как изменить кодировку на Python?

Tags: python

[image: Коллеги, доброго времени суток. Прошу вашей помощи]

Коллеги, доброго времени суток! Кто может помочь решить данный вопрос? гугление не принесло результатов!

Comment: Не знаю в каком гугле вы гуглили, но первых 10 ссылок об этом. Тут придется подождать чуть...

Comment: Пробовал те методы, но увы, поэтому сюда и обратился)

Comment: Это в Project Jupyter?

Comment: да, в нем самом